# Incremental load with lookup and timestamp in adf

Tags: azure, cloud, lookup, oracle-adf

I want to do in incremental load from an informieren dB to azure sql db. I used a lookup to get the latest time stamp from the sql db because full load  has already been done and I want to use the lookup output to get do incremental load. Here is my query

Select * from informixdb where select max(systemtimestamp) from informixdb) > @{activity('LookupSYS_TIME).output}

Comment: Could you please provide the error if you got any?

Comment: One error i got was because i used tab to indent my query and adf read it as an indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load the data incrementally You can follow below procedure:

In my case I am incrementally loading the data from db database to db1 database. I run below query in Lookup activity:

```
SELECT MAX(systemtimestamp) AS MaxTimestamp FROM student
```

[image]

After successful run of lookup activity added copy activity selected the db as source and added below query to the query tab:

```
Select * from student where systemtimestamp > '@{activity('LookupSYS_TIME').output.firstRow.MaxTimeStamp}'
```

[image]

I set the sink configuration as mentioned below:

[image]

After successful execution of pipeline the data loaded incrementally in db1:

[image]